# Quick loading of changed files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I am working on a ruby on rails application and I want to reduce the time it takes to "load" the application after changes are made to a couple of files. What I mean by that is after I make a few changes  in the ruby class files, in ruby on rails all the class files get reloaded on the local machine during the next request. This adds an additional **20 seconds-1 minute** to the time taken by the next request. How can I go about reducing the amount of time it takes for the next request that will hit the application. I want to bring the time it takes **to less than a second**. This issue only happens in the local machine when `config.cache_classes = false`

Comment: in a production environment, the files won't change, so this will become a "non-issue", right?

Comment: @Jad The issue happens in local machine and the time taken by the first request after the changes goes up by 3 minutes at times. This can be a real issue when you are trying to get work done quickly. So, I would appreciate any help or ideas on the matter.

Comment: Whats the size of your application? And what kind of environment are you using for development (VM, Docker, etc?) that sound extremely slow unless you're using a resource starved VM.

Comment: @max The application has around 200-300 models so I can say its pretty large. Don't know what kind of environment we are using  for development. How can I find out?